# PYTHON 3 function bug?

Tags: python, function, debugging

I'm having trouble with what I think MAY be a bug, or something that I'm missing.

This is the code:

```
#----------------------
import time
from time import sleep
#----------------------




class main():
     def menu():
        choice = input('Do you wish to register, or login?: ')
        if choice == 'register' or 'Register' or 'REGISTER':
            pass
        if choice == 'login' or 'Login' or 'LOGIN':
            main.login()



    def login():
        usr = 'SYSTEM'
        pas = 'DEFAULT'
        usr1 = input('Please type in your username credentials: ')
        pas1 = input('Now please type in your password: ')
        if usr != usr1 or pas != pas1:
            print('Your username and/or password is incorrect.Please try again.')
            time.sleep(3)
            main.login()
        if usr == usr1 and pas == pas1:
            print('Success!')




  def register():
    print('This feature is currently un-available. A defualt System password has been generated.\n Username: SYSTEM \n Password: DEFAULT \n')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('You will now be redirected to the login menu.\n')
    time.sleep(3)
    main.login()


main.menu()
```

If you run this code, you will see that if you attempt to login straight away, it will ALWAYS return the register function.
Is this a bug, or am I being stupid?
    Thanks,
       Ciaran

Comment: Note, this isn't an exact duplicate -- but only because you didn't realize where your problem was.  And by the way -- You're not being stupid.  I've seen this question LOTS of times on StackOverflow.  The problem is that python is _so_ expressive that occasionally we think it should be even more expressive than it actually is.

Comment: Im still quite not sure where im going wrong?

Comment: Compare your if statements in menu to those in login.

Comment: `choice == 'login' or 'Login' or 'LOGIN'` evaluates as `(choice == 'login') or 'Login'` -- (the last `'LOGIN'` is completely irrelevant).  Since `'Login'` is a non-empty string, it always evaluates to `True` in a boolean context.

Comment: You need `if choice == 'register' or choice == 'Register' or choice == 'REGISTER':` but better version is  `if choice.lower() == 'register':`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys, really appreciate it!